# Docker: Healthcheck-cmd using Healthchecks.io causing container to immediately fail after creation

Tags: docker, integration

I am trying to create a container using Healthchecks.io as the monitor. When the container is successfully created and stays running, the healthcheck never completes. It never pings healthchecks.io for any update. When checking "docker container list --all" after 60 seconds the healthcheck is constantly stating "health: starting" and never changes. The healthchecks.io website is never updated. I verified the image does have curl installed. This was not composed from a YAML but in inline "docker run"

What am I doing incorrectly or what am I doing wrong?

The container is: binhex/arch-delugevpn. I verified curl does exist in the container also.

```
     --health-cmd="/bin/curl -Ss --fail https://hc-ping.com/UUID || exit 1" \
     --health-interval=1h \
     --health-retries=5 \
     --health-timeout=5s \
     --health-start-period=60s \
```

Here is output of "docker inspect" after it is created.

```
"Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "/bin/curl -Ss --fail https://hc-ping.com/UUID || exit 1"
                ],
                "Interval": 3600000000000,
                "Timeout": 5000000000,
                "StartPeriod": 60000000000,
                "Retries": 12
```

I have tried manipulating placement of the quotes and types of quotes (None, double, and single) without and without " > /dev/null 2>&1" at end of the healthchecks.io site to possibly prevent problems. wget does not come with the container. The container creates but exits if I just place "curl" and not "/bin/curl" in the string.

Comment: In your example, the `--health-interval` is set to 1 hour. Are you waiting the full hour before checking if a ping was sent?

Comment: Why would it not start immediately or following "--health-start-period=300s \" then proceed with one hour checks thereafter?

Comment: From Docker docs: "The health check will first run interval seconds after the container is started, and then again interval seconds after each previous check completes.", "start period provides initialization time for containers that need time to bootstrap. Probe failure during that period will not be counted towards the maximum number of retries." https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Comment: There should be a bypass for that as in --healthcheck-delay-bootstrap=[no|time|yes] or something similar so it appears up immediately.

Comment: Or placing "--health-start-period" means startup when timer expires bypassing bootstrap startup delay and starts up when this timer expires.

Comment: `--health-start-period` parameter does not influence when Docker will run the first healthcheck probe. But, if a probe fails during this period, Docker will not count it as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following experiment – created a Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM binhex/arch-delugevpn
HEALTHCHECK --interval=20s --timeout=10s CMD curl https://hc-ping.com/my-uuid-here || exit 1
```

Built it:

```
docker build -t my-experiment .
```

And ran it:

```
docker run -it --rm my-experiment bash
```

I now see pings coming in every 20 seconds on Healthchecks.io, the reported curl version is `curl/7.88.1-DEV`.

Can you get this example to work?

I then tested it like so, by overriding the healthcheck command with command-line arguments:

```
docker run -it --rm \
    --health-cmd="curl https://hc-ping.com/my-uuid-here || exit 1" \
    --health-interval=20s \
    --health-timeout=10s \
    binhex/arch-delugevpn bash
```

This also worked, I'm seeing incoming pings every 20 seconds.

Comment: The container you supplied works instantly as it pings the healthcheck. When copied, added my UUID, then pasted to my run, the container is created, but never pings the UUID. Removed the "--health-start-period=300s \" and kept the "--health-interval=1h \" never pings.

binhex/arch-delugevpn   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute (health: starting)

Comment: OMG. I needed -t to allocate a TTY terminal. That was not in the docs that if if healthchecks is used that a TTY terminal must be allocated using -t.